# Unit Testing App Engine with Gorilla MUX

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, go, mux

I want to write tests for handlers in Google App Engine that use Gorilla mux to read variables from the request URL.

I understand from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/#Go_Introducing_the_aetest_package) that you can create a fake context and request to use with testing.

I'm calling the handler directly in the test but the handler isn't seeing the path parameter as expected.

```
func TestRouter(t *testing.T) {
  inst, _ := aetest.NewInstance(nil) //ignoring error for brevity
  defer inst.Close()
  //tried adding this line because the test would not work with or without it
  httptest.NewServer(makeRouter())
  req, _ := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/user/john@example.com/id-123", nil)
  req.Header.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
  resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
  restHandler(resp, req)
}

func restHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
  params := mux.Vars(r)
  email := params["email"]
  //`email` is always empty
}
```

The problem is that the handler always sees an empty "email" parameter because the path is not interpreted by Gorilla mux.

The router is as below:

```
func makeRouter() *mux.Router {
  r := mux.Router()
  rest := mux.NewRouter().Headers("Authorization", "").
    PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()

  app := r.Headers("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest").Subrouter()
  app.HandleFunc("/user/{email}/{id}", restHandler).Methods(http.MethodGet)

  //using negroni for path prefix /api
  r.PathPrefx("/api").Handler(negroni.New(
    negroni.HandlerFunc(authCheck), //for access control
    negroni.Wrap(rest),
  ))
  return r
}
```

All my searches have not gotten anything specific to App Engine unit testing with Gorilla mux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what you're testing is the handler, you could just get an instance of the router and call ServeHTTP on it. Here is how it should be based on your code.

**main.go**

```
func init() {
    r := makeRouter()
    http.Handle("/", r)
}

func makeRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    app := r.Headers("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest").Subrouter()
    app.HandleFunc("/user/{email}/{id}", restHandler).Methods(http.MethodGet)

    return r
}

func restHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    email := params["email"]
    fmt.Fprintf(w, email)
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
func TestRouter(t *testing.T) {
    inst, _ := aetest.NewInstance(nil) //ignoring error for brevity
    defer inst.Close()

    req, _ := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/user/john@example.com/id-123", nil)
    req.Header.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()

    r := makeRouter()
    r.ServeHTTP(rec, req)

    if email := rec.Body.String(); email != "john@example.com" {
        t.Errorf("router failed, expected: %s, got: %s", "john@example.com", email)
    }
}
```

Notice I removed the `rest` routes since that's not part of your test, but the idea would be the same. Also didn't check for errors for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think this works. At first I thought you suggested that I have to change the handler but upon closer reading, it is just helping to prove that the value is correctly read. I did a quick check and it seems to work. I'll mark this as the answer and update if there're any hiccups.

Comment: Awesome.. yeah, handlers are the same, the only difference is in test, and very minimal compared to what you have. Instead of calling the handler directly, you just create your mux router (`makeRouter`) and call `ServeHTTP` on it with your test request (`req`) and recorder (`rec`). Good luck!